# Django rendering selected form fields on a template

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Am trying to render a form having selected fields(i don't need all) for easy styling
**view.py**

```
class ProfileEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    form_class = UserChangeForm
    template_name = 'user/profile-update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('admin_dashboard')
    context_object_name='user'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

**urls.py**

```
path('profile/', ProfileEditView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

**profile-update.html**

```
{% extends 'garbage/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Profile {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="cont">
    <h1 class="form_title">Profile Details</h1>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="main_user_info">
                <div class="user_input_box">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update Profile">
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**style.css**

```
body {
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .cont {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        overflow: hidden;
        /* Hide overflow to make the circular border */
    }

    .form_title {
        color: #333;
        text-align: center;
    }

    form {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .main_user_info {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .user-profile-pic img {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20%;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .user-profile-pic {
        width: 150px;
        /* Adjust the width as needed */
        height: 150px;
        /* Adjust the height as needed */
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border: 4px solid #007bff;
        /* Add circular border around the image */
    }

    .user_input_box {
        width: 48%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    label {
        display: block;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    #id_username,
    #id_first_name,
    #id_last_name,
    input[type="email"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .form_btn {
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;

    }

    .btns {
        padding: 10px 20px;
        background-color: #007bff;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;

    }

    .btns:hover {
        background-color: #0056b3;
    }
```

```
the outcome i show in the attached picture just to give an iadea.
```

[image]

then after i tried to render the fields manually using some guide from a certain blog post i came with:

```
{% extends 'garbage/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %} Profile {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="cont">
    <h1 class="form_title">Profile Details</h1>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="main_user_info">
                <div class="user_input_box"> 
                    <label for="userame">Username:</label>
                    {{ form.username }} 
                </div>
                <div class="user_input_box"> 
                    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label> 
                    {{ form.first_name }} 
                </div> 
                <div class="user_input_box"> 
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label> 
                    {{ form.last_name }} 
                </div> 
                <div class="user_input_box"> 
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    {{ form.email }} 
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br><br>
            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update Profile">
        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

and the outcome looks like this(just what i want): [image: After selecting fields manually]

but the issue is that after rendering it manually form stops working, is there a way i can do it or there is something am not doing well.

rendered it manually using a ceratin blog post but the form stops working

tried rendering the fields manually but the form stops working, other fiedls i rendered manually are working fine just for this one.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?